# Some unknown blue icon on macos system bar

Tags: macos, icon, apple-silicon

What is that? Item does not respond to left or right clicks on icon. If somebody know what is that and how to remove it from top bar? (macos 13, Ventura[image])

Comment: Can you remove it by holding Command and dragging it away? But it would be good to figure out what it is first. Does Alt clicking on it do anything?

Comment: Is this a personal Mac, or a company-owned one?  That icon implies a remote control solution.